# Entity Framework and SQL Server Profiler

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, sql-server-profiler

I have some performance measuring issue between the **EF query** run through the web application and running the Profiler generated **T-SQL directly into the SQL Query window**.

Following is my EF query that executes through the web application:

```
IEnumerable<application> _entityList = context.applications
                    .Include(context.indb_generalInfo.EntitySet.Name)
                    .Include(context.setup_budget.EntitySet.Name)
                    .Include(context.setup_committee.EntitySet.Name)
                    .Include(context.setup_fund.EntitySet.Name)
                    .Include(context.setup_appStatus.EntitySet.Name)
                    .Include(context.appSancAdvices.EntitySet.Name)
                    .Where(e => e.indb_generalInfo != null);

                if (isIFL != null)
                    _entityList = _entityList.Where(e => e.app_isIFL == isIFL);

                int _entityCount = _entityList.Count(); // hits the database server at this line
```

While tracing the above EF Query in SQL Profiler it reveals that it took around **221'095 ms** to execute. (The applications table having 30,000+, indb_generalInfo having 11,000+ and appSancAdvices having 30,000+ records).

However, when I copy the T-SQL from Profiler and run it directly from Query window it takes around **4'000 ms** only.

Why is it so?

Comment: Have you tried to run the same query multiple time ? Entity Framework still needs to generate that query, but it will be cached for the future request. Also, if you're doing a `Count()`, there's is no need for eager loading.

Comment: Yes I had tried it earlier. But the issue was exactly what @Arnold notified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The venom in this query is in the first words: `IEnumerable<application>`. If you replace that by `var` (i.e. `IQueryable`) the query will be translated into SQL up to and including the last `Count()`. This will take considerably less time, because the amount of transported data is reduced to almost nothing.

Further, as bobek already mentioned, you don't need the `Include`s as you're only counting `context.applications` items.

Apart from that, you will always notice overhead of using an ORM like Entity Framework.

Comment: The EF implementation of IQueryable uses deferred execution so, as you say, the query is not translated into sql until Count() is called. You can also call AsEnumerable() or ToList() to force the translation and that is useful when you start using filters that can't be translated into sql. But AFAIK simply changing the variable declaration from IEnumerable to IQueryable will make no difference.

Comment: @Colin It will. Using `IEnumerable<application>` has the same effect as calling `AsEnumerable` after the first statement, thus forcing the records to be grabbed into memory before the rest of the LINQ statements will be applied, even though the execution of the query is deferred until the `Count`.

Comment: I tested this in my code by changing a variable declaration from var to IEnumerable<> and removing  a call to AsEnumerable() from a query that fails if passed into EF. And I can confirm that @Gert is correct. I stand corrected and I have learned something new today. So the comment in the question saying that the it "hits the database server at this line" is incorrect and that should be obvious from the query viewed in SQL Profiler - and the result will be a result set rather than an integer

Comment: Wait a minute - the database will be hit at Count - but the database query will return a resultset and the count will be done in memory right?

Comment: GertArnold! That really made a difference. I guess due to IEnumerable it was converting the 30k+ application objects as enumerable when hitting .Count(). Is it? @Colin, Why did you went on saying earlier that the query was not hitting the server at .Count()?

Comment: @Ali.NET Yes, that's what happened.

Comment: @GertArnold But one thing I am surprised of. Why it was taking 221'095ms in SQL Server Profiler then, if the delay was from EF side! :O

Comment: PS: As I required the result in List<T> object finally, so I converted the fetched records to List<T> after applying EF paging [.Skip() & .Take()] using List<T> constructor like this: List<application> lstApplications = new List<application>(_entityList)

Comment: @ali.net I thought for a second that the database hit would occur when you assign the result to an IEnumerable. That was incorrect. The query is deferred until the call to Count(). And at that point the database is hit. But the way this is coded means that the system will retrieve all the records from the database into memory  then get the count rather than just get the count from the database

Comment: @Colin Yes, i did require records count + individual (paged) records to display. That's why I tried to achieve both objectives from a single hit. And the performance improved drastically by applying Arnold solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's because EF needs to translate your code into TSQL first which is costly as well. Look at this link here: http://peterkellner.net/2009/05/06/linq-to-sql-slow-performance-compilequery-critical/ It'll let you compile your LINQ and should help you with the speed. Also, do you really need that many tables for this query? Maybe you can think of a way to filter it out and only pull out what you need?

Comment: since ef5 this should be cached now by default

Answer (score 0):

The EF definitely has a cost in terms of performance. But it also provides the flexibility to use storedprocs for complex TSQL. But in my opinion it should be your last resort.

Answer (score 0):

in case you interested re performance and EF.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx

However...

> EF Query in SQL Profiler it reveals that it took around 221'095 ms to
>   execute.

then..

> copy the T-SQL from Profiler and run it directly from Query window

Where the SQL came from is irrelevant.
Q1 took x millisecs.  Based on SQL profiler info
Exact same Query Q1' takes less based on SQL profiler.  Which means the source of the SQL isnt the issue, it implies environmental issues are involved.

The most obvious explanation, SQL server has buffered many data pages and can much better serve the second identical request.